# the physical address of code segment 682Bh and instruction pointer 0624h

Tags: assembly

I want to calculate the physical address of the following :

CS : 682Bh and IP:0624h

and DS: 782Dh, SI: 1022h .

How can I calculate physical address from the above  ?

Answer (score 1):

Always shift the value from the segment register 4 bits to the left, then add the value of the offset register:

```
682B0h
 0624h
-----
688D4h
```

and

```
782D0h
 1022h
-----
792F2h
```